# How to retrieve the initial configurations from a CMDB system and pass it to karate-config

Tags: karate

I have a situation. I need to send a get request to a CMDB system and retrieve the initial configurations like endpoint URI, path, DB connection string etc as a JSON object. The CMDB system will send back a JSON object. How I can implement this in karate-config.js. Am I supposed to write a custom javascript function or do I have any inbuilt capabilities? I checked the karate object section, however, did not understand how to do it.

I wrote few custom js functions for this. They work independently in my system(I have node.js installed on my machine), but will not work inside karate-config.js.

**First one**

```
var HttpClient = function () {
    this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
        var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
        anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
        anHttpRequest.send(null);
    }
}


var url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get(url, function (response) {
    var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response1)
});
```

**Second**

```
var axios = require('axios');
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2').then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are forgetting that Karate happens to be very good at making HTTP requests :)

All you need to do is write a re-usable Karate feature file that makes a `GET` to `https://reqres.in/api/users/2`. You may need to figure out any headers needed.

There is a `karate.callSingle()` method that can now be used in `karate-config.js` to do exactly what you want. Look at line 31:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/karate-config.js#L31